# PHP: Alternative to variables passed by reference?

Tags: php

In the minutes [php6 developer meeting](http://www.php.net/~derick/meeting-notes.html#deprecated-behaviour), i came across a point where it said that call-time-pass-by-reference is no longer there in PHP6. For example, following both are incorrect for PHP6:

```
<?php
$foo =& new StdClass();
?>

<?php
function &foo()
{
    return new StdClass();
}

$f = foo();
?>
```

If we can't use something like this in PHP6:

```
$foo =& new StdClass();
```

What is the alternative to that, is there any way to mimic that?

**EDIT:**

Ans what about variables in PHP6, can we do that for variables eg:

```
$this->data =& $_SESSION;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't **pass** parameters by reference, but you still can/must declare your function/method as **receiving** parameters by reference.

i.e., you don't do this *(passing parameters by reference)* :

```
my_function(& $my_var);

function my_function($a) {
    // ...
}
```

But you can do this *(declaring the function as receiving parameters by reference)* :

```
my_function($my_var);

function my_function(& $a) {
    // ...
}
```

And... The code examples you gave are not related to *call-time-pass-by-reference*, but are related to *return-by-reference*.

For that second thing, what if you just remove the `&` ? The instance of the object that's been created inside the function will be returned, and you'll still be able to work with it, won't you ?

Comment: thanks for your answer, plz see my edit below question, thanks

Comment: also i am not talking about functions, i am talking about call-time-pass-by-reference.

Comment: Call-time pass-by-reference *is* to do with functions. `my_function(&$a);` is passing `$a` to `my_function` by reference at call-time, rather than at declare-time.

Comment: @Sarfraz Ahmed : hu... call-time-by-reference is about functions and methods : it's the passing of parameters to functions/methods by reference when calling them, instead of declaring them as receiving parameters by reference ;; it has nothing to do with your edit, which is just/only assignment by reference

Comment: @Pascal: is that assignment by reference correct and not deprecated/removed from php6?

Comment: To be sure, I would say "try" ; but I don't think it (assigment of variables by reference) actually is deprecated. Still note that PHP 6 is not there yet, and many things can still change (there have been talks about PHP 6 at least those past 2 years, and it still isnt in alpha yet)

Answer (score 5):

Objects are always passed by reference since PHP5, so this:

```
$foo =& new StdClass();
```

is the same as:

```
$foo = new StdClass();
```

.

Comment: thanks for your answer, plz see my edit below question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Ans what about variables in PHP6, can we do that for variables eg:
>   `$this->data =& $_SESSION;`

I see no reason why not -- PHP will not be removing references, as they are far too useful. There is no other way to create a reference to a variable.

Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated for a while. It just means that instead of doing this:

```
function foo($a) { return ++$a; }
foo(&$my_a);
```

You would do this:

```
function foo(&$a) { return ++$a; }
foo($my_a);
```

This leads to a much cleaner and easier-to-understand programming style, and it also ensures that variables are always referenced when you expect, and not when you don't.

Dealing with objects is a special case -- they are always passed by reference, and the only way to simulate pass-by-value is to use `clone`:

```
$a = new StdClass();
$a->foo = 'bar';
$b = $a;
$a->foo = 'qux';
// $b->foo is 'qux' too

$a = new StdClass();
$a->foo = 'bar';
$b = clone $a;
$a->foo = 'qux';
// $a->foo is 'qux' but $b->foo is 'bar'
```

Hope that helps!